# Orientation in Table View Controller?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ios-simulator

I have a Table View Controller (root) and 5 View Controllers in my project. The view Controllers turn only to landscape view (as I want) but not the Table View Controller (only in the Portrait view).In supported Device Orientations I deleted Portrait and Upside down, and I wrote in every class:

- (BOOL) shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation 
  {
  return ((interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) || (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight));

Any suggestions to make Table view turn only to landscape view?

Comment: I also have a UITableViewController and it never goes to portrait mode when I forbid it like you did with the shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation function

Comment: Actually, in the Simulator it turns to landscape view, but the rows of the TableViewController don't turn  (stay in Portrait view)...

Comment: Have you changed frame of table in willRotate... method?

Comment: I haven't done any willRotate method, only the above: shouldAutorotate...

Answer (score 0):

put this in the viewDidLoad

```
self.tableView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
```

Comment: Shall I create a new class for the TableViewController or put in ViewController.m in viewDidLoad?

Comment: Do I need to create a property for the Tableview in .h?

Comment: no you said you have a TableViewController (root) .. put this code inside it.

Comment: I am really sorry. I do apollogize is not a root controller the Table view.

Comment: ok so put it in the view controller that contain the tableView .. if you define the table just replace self.tableView With the name of your table.

Comment: Well, I replaced tableView with view,  I put in viewDidLoad in ViewController.m and didn't change anything.

Comment: Do I need to define Tableview?

Comment: In IB when I mark(with blue line) TableViewController, in attributes   ->custom class->class, it shows that belongs to the UITableViewController( With low opacity letters). When I press the little arrow on the right it appears on the screen UITableViewController.h, in which is written:

Comment: @property(nonatomic,retain)UITableview*tableView;

Comment: when I put in ViewController.m: self.tableView.ViewController.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;

Comment: it says:property ""tableView" not found on object of type "ViewController"

Comment: there is no property called tableview.viewcontroller ! just take a copy the code i put above and past it in your viewcontroller.m

Comment: Every time I paste it in viewcontroller.m it gives this error:property "tableView" not found on object of type "ViewController"

Comment: I declared in viewController.h: @property(nonatomic,retain)UITableView*tableView;                    it runs but in Portrait view.

Comment: there is a misunderstanding .. can you tell me where is your tableview .. did you create it and make it IBOutlet ? or your class is subclass of UITableViewController ?

Comment: I declared in main ViewController.h: @property... and then paste the code in ViewController.m. Should I write in main ViewController.h: @property(nonatomic,retain)UIViewController*tableView??

Comment: it gives me an error:property "autoresizingMask" not found on object of type "UIViewController"

Comment: George just tell me where is your tableview ??

Comment: When I mark Table View Controller in Storyboard, in attributes, in referencing Outlets it says: data source - Table view. delegate- Table view

Comment: Man you are define @property(nonatomic,retain)UIViewController *tableView !!! its a tableView not a view controller ... replace UIViewController With **UITableView**